# How can I enlarge an item of a Listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I add items to a Listbox using this code:

```
item.Text = Name;
item.Tag = text;
item.Image = Image1;
ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

When I mouseover, I want to enlarge the image in the Listbox.

How can I access that item (Image) of the Listbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
private void myListBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e){

   Point point = myListBox.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
   int index = myListBox.IndexFromPoint(point); //this wil give index

}
```

Comment: yes. i got the index. but i don't know how i can acess width or height of the image.. i tried like Listbox1.items[index].Image.width... but it didn't work..

Comment: `ListBox1.Items[index].Image` gives your the image, then you can modify the height and width from there.

Comment: i use database(mysql). so Image1 include information of image

Comment: yes this should give your image then , ListBox1.Items[index].Image

Comment: yes. i already tried ListBox1.Items[index].Image. but it was error T_T

Comment: Could you give the error name/message? That would help in identifying the problem.

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Image' and no extension method 'Image' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: your item does not have a image property?

Comment: Realized this wasn't WPF xD, this is the correct answer, you are just missing casting your object to the item in the listbox to access its image `var image = ((item)ListBox1.Items[index]).Image` where item is your object type.

Comment: when debugging, i checked that Image is included in the Listbox1.Items[index]... But In SourceCode, i can't use Listbox1.items[index].Image...

Comment: Need to check the code !

Comment: Thank u very much ! i think i can solve it

Comment: mark as answer if it helped